# Supply value for a parameter in powershell

Tags: powershell

I would like to incorporate [this](https://gist.github.com/tylerapplebaum/dc527a3bd875f11871e2) function in my script and So I am trying to define the $target parameter with an IP so the script doesn't prompt for a target ip and it automatically executes with the IP thats defined in the script. I tried what is below but its obviously not working.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
  param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
  [String] $target= "8.8.8.8",
```

Comment: whats not working about it? How do you know its not working?

Comment: it still prompts me for $target

Comment: You need to remove `Mandatory=$True`

Comment: Dont forget to mark the answer correct if it solves your issue. We are here for the internet points after all :)

Comment: ty so much.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you have a Parameter using `Mandatory=$True`

If `Mandatory=$True` then it will always ask for that value even if you have a optional value used.

The fix would be

```
[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
[String] $target= "8.8.8.8",
```